# How to configure log4j and logback to log into one single file properly?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j, logback

I have a java web app that uses logback with slf4j for logging. 
And this project has a dependency jar (which is a sub project). And this dependency jar uses org.apache.log4j.Logger for logging.
All logs must go into one log file.
My problem is, whatever I am logging with the code in the jar file is not being written to the log file.
Initially I had logback.xml. To resolve the above problem I added log4j.properties file to my web app. 
It resolved my problem and now I can see all logs in one file.

Again my new probelm is: Earlier the log file was rolling every day according to the rolling policy in logback.xml.
Now it is not rolling. Even after I configured the rolling policy in log4j.properties that matches with the rolling policy that is in logback.xml, rolling is not happening.

I don't want to replace log4j in my dependency with logback. And also I want to write alll my logs into one file.
Is it possible to this, how can I resolve my issue?

FYI: I have "log4j-over-slf4j" dependency included in my pom.xml

Log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=SOME_PATH/logs/studentApp.log
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy = org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern = SOME_PATH/logs/studentApp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log    
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=14
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your rolling policy is correct, it's possible that log4j picks up the wrong configuration. log4j looks for the first configuration file in the classpath (first `.xml` then `.properties`) and if it happens to be the configuration from one of your dependencies your rolling policy will not work.

To test this you can add a system property `-Dlog4j.configuration=...` with the path to your configuration to the tomcat startup script. Or simply set your log level to TRACE/DEBUG and see if it affects the output.

**Edit:** your log4j config looks good, but the date pattern is missing.
Try adding
`log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm` (note that I've set the pattern to roll-over every minute, for easier testing)

**Edit**: you can remove every line containing `rollingPolicy` and `maxBackupIndex` - those will not be picked up in this case

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have any configuration for log4j in my dependency

Comment: have you tried to change the debug level to make sure your config is picked up correctly? maybe there's just something wrong with your rolling policy

Comment: I have edited my question to show my properties file. Please see it let me know if there anything wrong in it,, thanks

Comment: I tried with debug level set to DEBUG, and I noticed that it picks up the config correctly

Comment: I did what have said in your edit, now it is rolling, but the file name is wrong. For example instead of studentApp.2016-03-17-10-53.log it shows  studentApp.log.2016-03-17-10-53, so I can't open the file, do you have any idea??

Comment: See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066040/configure-rolling-log4j-log-file-name

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration will create a .log file for the current date and keep adding the log in that file. When the date chanages, it will create a new file with the current date. This configuration will also zip the files as or when they exceed a certain size limit.

```
    <appender name="FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <fileNamePattern>log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.zip</fileNamePattern>

                          <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                                <!-- or whenever the file size reaches 500MB -->
                                <maxFileSize>300MB</maxFileSize>
                        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Hope it helps.